# Ruby on Rails with Haml - how to switch from erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I am in the process of switching to HAML from erb files. 
I added the haml gem to my system.  I created the app/views/layouts/application.html.haml file.  Should I just delete the application.html.erb file?

Also, there is still the /public/index.html file which gets rendered as the default page. I want to make my own default index.html.haml page.  Where do I place it and how do I make the system render that file instead of the default index file?

Thanks!

Comment: You may also want to install the gem `haml-rails` to have generators use HAML over ERB by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can just delete the ERB version of any views you have converted over to HAML.

As for your other question, delete the public/index/html file. Next, you may want to add a PagesController and have an action in there like index, and a corresponding view, and put your 
"home page" stuff in there.

Then in your routes file, add:

```
root :to => "pages#index"
```

Comment: thanks, just one thing..so should I place the new index.html.haml file right in the app/views/ directory?

Comment: No.  If you follow the rest of MrDanA's suggestions you should put the  index.html.haml file in the app/views/pages/ folder.  That's where the route he described says it will be.

Answer (score 3):

u can autoconvert and delete all erb files using this script

```
for i in `find app/views -name '*.erb'` ; do html2haml -e $i ${i%erb}haml ; rm $i ; done
```

And simply delete index.html in public folder